# Regarding The os.fork() Function In Python

Tags: python, fork

I'm just beginning with python and I developed a simple program to fork a parent process. Here's the code I've written so far...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

def child():
    print "We are in the child process with PID= %d"%os.getpid()

def parent():
    print "We are in the parent process with PID= %d"%os.getpid()
    newRef=os.fork()
    if newRef==0:
        child()
    else:
        print "We are in the parent process and our child process has PID= %d"%newRef

parent()
```

From what I understand, the code should begin by calling the parent process and display its PID. Afterwards, the `os.fork()` is called and it creates a copy of the parent process, and since we are already in the parent process, the `newRef` variable should contain a value that is positive and the `else` part of my code is the one that should be executed. My question is that: why did the code initiate to call the `child()` function afterwards although the `if` part of my code should not execute.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: These are an absolute bear to trace when they get more complicated. The one thing to remember is that when you call that fork() function, it creates an EXACT in-memory duplicate of the current process at that EXACT point. try running `if fork() != fork(): fork()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After you return from `fork`, you now have *two processes* executing the code immediately following `fork`.

So your statement:

> since we are already in the parent process

is only half-true. After `os.fork` returns, the parent process continues executing the code as the parent process, but the child process continues executing the *exact same code* with the same local and global variables, with the exception of the return value of `fork`. So, from the child process's perspective, `newRef` has the value of `0`, and from the parent's perspective, `newRef` has a positive value. Both processes will execute the code accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

When you call `os.fork`, you create a new process that is an exact copy of the existing process *except* that in the original process, `fork` returns the process ID of the new (child) process, and in the new process, `fork` returns `0`. This difference is how you can do something different in the parent and in the child.

In your specific code, the return value of `fork` in the child is `0`, so the child process calls the `child` function. In the parent, the return value is not `0`, so the else clause is executed.